# Allocate pseudo TTY in Upstart configuration file

Tags: sudo, upstart

We would like to use Upstart to manage a Java process and run it as non-root using sudo. We are on RHEL 6 which means that Upstart is too old to allow us to explicitly specify a user hence the use of sudo.

However, the Sudo configuration file specifies `Defaults requiretty` which means we can't run `sudo -u` to launch the command as a non-root user. We get the following error

`sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Is there a way to get Upstart to allocate a pseudo TTY so that sudo will allow us to launch this process? The sudoers file is set according company policy and we are unable to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to - and shouldn't - use `sudo` to change users *in an init script*. Use `su` or better, `runuser` instead. The `runuser` command should be available from RHEL 5 and will do the right thing with respect to SELinux contexts, etc.

```
runuser -u username -g groupname command arguments
```